# js containsNode не работает с крайними элементами

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, range

Разрабатываю простенький wysiwyg-редактор. Есть html структура с текстовым содержанием "Привет это мир", хочу определить, выбрана ли вся строка целиком или только часть, для этого вызываю в цикле метод containsNode для каждого элемента, но он отказывается работать с крайними элементами. Ниже код, выделите слово "мир" целиком и нажмите на кнопку, метод containsNode всегда будет возвращать false. Как быть?

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
   
btn.onclick = function() {

  var select = window.getSelection();
  var elem = document.getElementById('r');

  alert(select.containsNode(elem));
  
}
```

```html
<i><b><u>Привет </u></b><b>это</b><b id="r"> мир</b></i>
<button id="btn">Кпопка</button>
```

Comment: А то, что у вас в элементе ещё пробел и он не выделен, разве не должно влиять так на результат?

Comment: Выделите с пробелом, да хоть строку целиком, результат false. Выдает true только если выделить все элементы тройным нажатие.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, при ручном выделении даже всего текста элемента, вы не можете гарантированно добиться того, чтобы сам элемент попал внутрь выделения. Мои эксперименты на скорую руку показывают, что при выделении всего текста элемента, `anchorNode` и `focusNode` могут равняться текстовому узлу внутри элемента, так что сам элемент может быть полностью вне выделения, хоть и всё содержимое его выделено. Наверное, вам стоит вдобавок к вашей проверке проверять, содержатся ли внутри выделения все текстовые узлы элемента (или равняется ли длина выделения (или `focusOffset`/`anchorOffset`) длине этих текстовых узлов).

Comment: Спасибо, предполагаю, что придется писать свою функцию вместо containsNode

Comment: Ну, там ведь можно просто запустить containsNode для всех childNodes, вдруг этого будет достаточно.

Comment: Что-то вроде `return select.containsNode(elem) || [...elem.childNodes].every(node => select.containsNode(node));`.